# Combining two complicated queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have two separate queries, both of which work.

```
SELECT MAX(instances) 
FROM (
    SELECT FK_Hour, day As day, Count(FK_Hour) As instances 
    FROM (
        Select slottime.FK_Hour, time.day 
        From slottime INNER JOIN time ON slottime.FK_Hour = time.Hour 
        ) As C 
    GROUP By FK_Hour 
    ) AS counts 
GROUP By day
```

and

```
Select slot.SlotNo As FK_SlotNo 
FROM 
    (Programme INNER JOIN Module 
        ON Programme.COURSE = Module.FK_Course) 
    INNER JOIN (Slot 
                INNER JOIN SlotDemo ON Slot.SlotNo = SlotDemo.FK_SlotNo) 
         ON Module.ModuleCode = Slot.FK_ModuleCode 
GROUP BY Slot.SlotNo, Programme.C_val 
HAVING (((Count(SlotDemo.FK_Demonstrator))<5) AND ((Programme.C_val)<6))
```

The first query is the meat of the matter, but I'm looking to refine its results (using the second query).

However, the result is a bit of a mess (and, no huge surprises, doesn't work):

```
SELECT MAX(instances) 
    FROM (SELECT FK_Hour, day As day, Count(FK_Hour) As instances 
        FROM (Select slottime.FK_Hour, slottime.FK_SlotNo, time.day 
            From slottime INNER JOIN time ON slottime.FK_Hour = time.Hour ) 
                FROM (Select slot.SlotNo As FK_SlotNo
                    FROM (Programme INNER JOIN Module ON Programme.COURSE = Module.FK_Course) INNER JOIN (Slot INNER JOIN SlotDemo ON Slot.SlotNo = SlotDemo.FK_SlotNo) ON Module.ModuleCode = Slot.FK_ModuleCode
                    GROUP BY Slot.SlotNo, Programme.C_val
                    HAVING (((Count(SlotDemo.FK_Demonstrator))<5) AND ((Programme.C_val)<6)))
            As C GROUP By FK_Hour   
        ) 
        AS counts GROUP By day
```

Yikes.

Can't help but feel that I'm going about this entirely wrong. Should I be attempting a union of the two queries - or something entirely different?

[image: relationships of tables]

Note this is a mysql database, the relationship view of access is for illustration only.

Comment: The first query doesn't really seem to make a whole lot of sense. You're just going to be getting a indeterminate (usually "last") `day` from the inner `GROUP BY`, which you later use for the outer `GROUP BY`; and the innermost query doesn't actually need to be a subquery of the one encompassing it.

Comment: @Uueerdo No it does work - it returns a number for each day which is really what I'm looking for. I've tested it with sample data and there seems to be no problems with it.

Comment: What database are you using? If your db supports CTEs, that might be a good option.

Comment: As @Uueerdo noted, the first query doesn't make a lot of sense.  Many databases would reject it outright on account of selecting a column from an aggregate query that is not a function of the groups. MySQL accepts such queries as an extension, but does not define from which rows the values of such columns will be drawn.  Under certain circumstances that's acceptable and even useful, but trying to wrap the result in an inline view that groups by such a column seems unlikely to be one of those circumstances.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it won't be 1, it'll be the number of records in the `time` table with that FK_Hour... regardless of day.

Comment: @Uueerdo, my bad, you're right.  I've deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first query is trying to determine the number of slots scheduled on the day that has the most slots scheduled.  It's kinda hinky, but upon careful analysis, I suspect it computes that correctly.  Given the relationships you presented, though, this would be a better starting point:

```
select max(sph.instances)
from (
    select FK_Hour, count(*) as instances
    from slottime
    group by FK_Hour
  ) sph
  join time t
    on sph.FK_Hour = t.Hour
group by t.day
```

Eliminating one nested query and lifting the join from the innermost query to the outer one works because you are joining to the whole primary key of table `Time`, and table `SlotTime` has a foreign key relationship with it.  That join therefore neither filters out any rows nor adds any rows to the results.  It serves only to associate the `day` column with the results, so that you can group by it in the outermost query.  The alternative I've presented is not only easier to understand, it's also standard SQL.

Your second query is formatted oddly, but appears basically sound.  When you say you want refine the results of the first query via the second, I guess you mean you want to restrict the `SlotTime`s on which the first draws to those associated with `Slot`s determined via the second.  Here's one way to do that:

```
select max(sph.instances)
from (
    select FK_Hour, count(*) as instances
    from slottime
      join (
        select slot.SlotNo As FK_SlotNo 
        from Programme
          join Module 
            on Programme.COURSE = Module.FK_Course
          join Slot
            on Module.ModuleCode = Slot.FK_ModuleCode 
          join SlotDemo
            on Slot.SlotNo = SlotDemo.FK_SlotNo 
        group by Slot.SlotNo, Programme.C_val 
        having (Count(SlotDemo.FK_Demonstrator) < 5) AND (Programme.C_val < 6)
      ) s
      on slottime.FK_SlotNo = s.FK_SlotNo
    group by FK_Hour
  ) sph
  join time t
    on sph.FK_Hour = t.Hour
group by t.day
```

That uses an inner join to perform the extra filtering.  Alternatively, you could use a `WHERE` clause with an `IN` condition to accomplish the same thing.

Note that this depends heavily on the relationship structure you presented.  In particular, it assumes that the original second query will not return any duplicates, which in turn depends on every `Slot.SlotNo` to be associated with at most one `Programme.C_val`.  It is your relationship structure that ensures that, not the query.

Comment: Ah... I was hoping to have my cake and eat it. Is is disappointing that being ordered by day seems not to really be a possibility. I suppose that is the fault of the structure I employed, but I had (and still do) have motives in relation to how it will be processed by the scripting language which it has been moulded to fit.

Comment: If you want specific result ordering, then you should add an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.  Grouping does not imply ordering.

Comment: Okay, but what I mean is that the combined query (unlike the first one in your answer) seems to, unfortunately, return only the very last row (or last day).